# Übersetzung von "in late June"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, time

> The event takes place every year in late June.

Wie lässt sich dieser Satz ins Deutsche übersetzen?

> (a) Die Veranstaltung findet jedes Jahr im späten Juni statt.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob "im späten Juni" umständlich oder gar richtig klingt. Eine andere Möglichkeit, aber vielleicht mit einer Änderung in der Bedeutung:

> (b) Die Veranstaltung findet jedes Jahr am Ende Juni statt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd simply use »Ende Juni« (without preposition), like so:

> Die Veranstaltung findet jedes Jahr Ende Juni statt.

Comment: Wobei "im späten" nicht falsch wäre, "am Ende" aber schon. "Am Ende" ist zudem eine Phrase, die eine ganz andere Bedeutung in den Satz bringt. "Am Ende findet die Veranstaltung noch statt!"